# Error 1000: AFx Library library exception: Type Decimal is not supported

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to query a MS Access Web App (SQL Azure) using the Azure ML platform. The field I'm trying to capture is type `Fixed-point number (6 decimal places)`, the default numeric field type in Azure SQL. When I try to query this field, I get the error:

`Error 1000: AFx Library library exception: Type Decimal is not supported`

I have tried casting it to another form like follows:

`select cast(a) FROM b`

And got the error:

`Error 0069: SQL query "select cast("a" as float) from "b"" is not correct:
Column names cannot be null or empty.`

What gives?

Furthermore, how isn't the default on Azure SQL supported in Azure ML???

Comment: When casting try providing alias liek select cast(a ...) as 'someAlias' FROM b

Comment: Correct! That worked beautifully. Being more complete: The winning solution was: `select cast("field" as float) as 'someAlias' FROM "Table"`. Thanks! Answer for rep?

Comment: No worries, glad it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per serhiyb's answer, the win was to assign it to another variable:

`Select cast("field" as float) as 'someAlias' FROM "Table"`